# How to get Video and Audio Metadata using Exoplayer on AndroidTV

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x, leanback

I am building an Android TV application using **Leanback** framework. I went through the Android TV Sample and inside the Leanback sample, there is **VideoPlayerGlue** which is using **LeanbackPlayerAdapter**. Now what I am trying to achieve here is when my Video is played on the **ExoPlayer**, I would like to fetch the Video Resolution (2160p, 1080p, 720p etc.) and Audio Channels (2.0, 5.1, 7.1) and display this information with the title of the Player (by using playerGlue.setSubtitle()).

I am just wondering how can I fetch this Audio/Video metadata? also where exactly should that functionality be implemented to fetch the metadata implemented ideally? Should it be inside the PlaybackFragment or VideoPlayerGlue or LeanbackPlayerAdapter?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can fetch data in PlaybackFragment because this is your main class so you can transfer the data to further classes.